# How to make drag-and-drop docking panels?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I would like to have dockable panels using jquery that behave much like the ones in Visual Studio. Mainly, I just want to be able to drag and drop panels to any side of the screen. Tabs, floating windows, and auto-hide panels are not necessary. When two or more panels are dropped on to the same side, they should share the space on that side of the screen. The user should be able to resize the panels.

Is there a jQuery and/or jQuery UI plugin that can do this? Or maybe a tutorial?

Comment: Yes there are ways to do something similar with jquery.     Google on jquery drag and drop

Comment: Also see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784574/a-full-page-layout-with-resizable-panes-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Jquery UI to accomplish all of this.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Below is an example of a drag and drop page I made.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that is just dragging and dropping in general. I'm asking if someone has already made a docking panel/window library for jQuery so that I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel, this will handle everything with little effort.  It has snap-to-grid functionality which is perfect for docking.  Alls you need to do is create a 'dockable' area and than create dockable items.

Comment: Use the control from this site. It is open source with MIT license.  http://www.dockspawn.com/#

Comment: Do you think you could edit your answer to provide a little JSFiddle example of how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I've used the jQuery UI Layout which provides all of the functionality except the drag-drop and since this rides on top of jQuery we can use jQuery UI drag-drop as needed.

[jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)

I recently found out this new control which is what need exactly.

http://www.dockspawn.com/#

Another layout manager worth looking at

https://github.com/WebCabin/wcDocker

we are using this one of our projects and it is quite helpful.

Most Recently I found [lobiPanel](https://github.com/arboshiki/lobipanel/blob/master/README.md), and I've used that to create a fantastic looking portal. I'm loving it.

Comment: Thanks for Dockspawn info, interesting to discover a new programming language "Dart" behind the dockspawn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to jquery, here Is an impressive docking manager that allows to use multiple windows:
http://golden-layout.com/examples/
(Try the "Open in new window" buttons)

On the FAQ page there is a list of alternative layout managers:
http://golden-layout.com/faq/