# jQuery resizable panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to find `jQuery` plugin which will be create resizable areas, something like this:

[image]

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784574/a-full-page-layout-with-resizable-panes-using-jquery-ui), but all plugins in that topic not very good in my opinion. Maybe somebody knows something better?

Comment: Why aren't they good ? Tell us more !

Answer (score 0):

Found a great example [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/layout/). Check out [this site](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/documentation.cfm#Demos) for some demos.