# How to create vertical drag-to-resize divider?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[Example of the divider](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)

The center divider can be dragged to resize the left and right divs. It appears that dragging the divider will change the CSS `width` value as a percentage, but I don't know what's causing that value to change.

I'd like to create something similar to this, where a divider can be dragged to resize the left and right divs, and any content inside those divs will be fitted. How can this be done?

Potential compatibility issue to avoid: Eventually, I'd also like to make it responsive on mobile screens using `@media` to hide the right div while the left is visible, and hide the left div when the right is visible.

Comment: I'm using chrome. When I mouseover the divider a box pops up in the corner that says `javascript:void(0)`. So it looks like this divider is controlled by Javascript.

Comment: @Polyov Do you know what that `javascript:void(0)` does?

Comment: It doesn't really mean or do anything. You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean) for more info on the practice. But it's a good indicator that JS is at play.

Comment: @Polyov How can I find the JS that's associated with it?

Comment: You can use a dom inspector to find the event handlers that are bound to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to do a split pane in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194469/best-way-to-do-a-split-pane-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery UI is probably the esiest way to achieve this. Here is a example of how you could start with that: [A full page layout with resizable panes using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784574/a-full-page-layout-with-resizable-panes-using-jquery-ui)

Also, look int the CSS resize property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

I don't think it's exactly what you want but you could combine it with some css to achieve a similar effect without JavaScript.

Comment: As of this comment writing, the `resize` property isn't widely supported. Check the current support here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize